# how to convert dict value use lambda map in python

Tags: python-3.x

the format data like this, To explain, I have this dict:

```
{
'41': [
        '1029136700',
        '1028348931'
    ],
'42': ['12234454']
 ...
}
```

then i want to convert the format like this used lambda and map:

```
[
        {
          'key':'41','value':'1029136700'
        },
        {
          'key':'41','value': '1028348931'
        },
        {
          'key':'42', 'value': '12234454'
        }
        ...
            ]
```

Can you give me a clue on how to achieve this in python?

Comment: Can't be done.  Dicts in Python have unique keys.

Comment: You can not repeat the key of a dict. Only the last value to be left.

Comment: You can't have duplicate keys in Python dicts.

Comment: That was misstated， i just edit the question.@StephenRauch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a clue on how to get what you want - you have to iterate over the initial dictionary:

```
for key, list_of_vals in initial_dictionary.items():
    for val in list_of_vals:
        # now you have pairs
        # for example, key = '41', val = '1029136700'
        # use them as you need
```

Just couple more steps and you get exactly what you want.

However, if you want to do this with `map()` and `lambda` it would not be that easy. You have to replace every for loop (there 2 of them) with `map()` containing `lambda`. `map()` returns generator so you have to iterate over it to get actual result, for example, `list(map(...))`. Here is complete code how you can get what you want:

```
result = list()

set(map(lambda item: result.extend(list(
            map(lambda val: {'key': item[0], 'value': val},
                item[1]))),
        initial_dictionary.items()))

print(result)
```

Output:

```
[{'key': '41', 'value': '1029136700'}, {'key': '41', 'value': '1028348931'}, {'key': '42', 'value': '12234454'}]
```

This implementation is significantly more difficult to read and understand.